# Dynamically adding list to a nested list in jQuery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying to add a list to a `<li>` after a user clicks on the `li`. The list is being added but the list is not opening on a new page. See the [nested list](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/lists/lists-nested.html) example on `jQuery` mobile site. When you click on a `list` node, the sub list is opening in a new page (kind of). I want the same functionality while dynamically adding list.

Here is my code http://jsfiddle.net/f869z/. When you click on a `<li>` its adding the new list but not in the same fashion as shown in the jQuery mobile site.

How can I achieve this functionality? Otherwise what is the preferred way to add nested list dynamically.

EDIT: This problem has been solved by refreshing the list view. Now I am adding a listview inside collapsible dynamically. But inside that list, when I am clicking a `<li>`, `pageinit` event is getting fired instead of `click` event. The click event is getting fired when we click the same `li` second time.

Updated code: http://jsfiddle.net/5zJC5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated your jsfiddle example so that it works. Check the jsFiddle example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tolis/f869z/1/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>jQuery Mobile Nested List</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).on('click', '#list li', function() {    
                $(this).append("<ul><li>Subcategory 1 <ul> <li data-role=\"list-divider\">Sub category</li> <li data-icon=\"false\">Test 1</li> <li data-icon=\"false\">Test 2</li> </ul> </li> <li>Subcategory 2 <ul> <li data-role=\"list-divider\">Sub category</li> <li data-icon=\"false\">Test 1</li> <li data-icon=\"false\">Test 2</li> </ul> </li></ul>").parent().listview('refresh');
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="list-page" data-role="page">
            <div data-role="header">
                 <h1>Nested List Page</h1>

            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
                <div data-role="collapsible-set" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="d">
                    <div data-role="collapsible">
                        <h3 data-position="inline">Filtered list<h3>
                        <ul data-role="listview" data-divider-theme="d" id="list">
                            <li><a href="#">Adam Kinkaid</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Alex Wickerham</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Avery Johnson</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Bob Cabot</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Caleb Booth</a></li>
                        </ul> 
                    </div> 
                </div> 
            </div> 
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

I hope this helps

Comment: but its not adding the sub lists dynamically. I want that the sub list should be added when the user click on a parent list. See my jsfiddle in the question

Comment: I updated the answer. Select the category 1. Inside the script you should put your code which fills the nested list.

Comment: I changed your jsfiddle example so that it works. I have updated my answer. http://jsfiddle.net/tolis/f869z/1/

Comment: Can you explain what is the problem in this code? I am adding a listview inside collapsible dynamically. But inside that list, when I am clicking a <li>, pageinit event is getting fired instead of click event. The click event is getting fired when we click the same li second time. Code: http://jsfiddle.net/5zJC5/

Comment: You should create a new question. The initial issue was resolved.. Now you've changed the context the description of the problem.